# How to total a column in a table based on filter criteria from two other columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following Table as an example:

```
Name     Task     Amount     
Jennifer Sing     10
Tom      Dance    15
Joe      Jump     72
Mandy    Scream   10
```

And supporting lists:

```
Names       Tasks       
Jennifer    Dance
Joe         Sing
            Jump
```

I need to find the total of the sum of amounts where Name is in the Names list AND Task is in the Tasks list.  In other words, if the person AND the task are in the list of relevant people and tasks, total their amount.

So, for example, the total would be 10+72=82.

I have tried to name the ranges of the criteria lists as RelevantNamesList and RelevantTasksLists, and the input table columns as Names and Tasks and Hours, and then using sumif, however I am not even able to get it to work with a single condition.

```
=SUMIF( Names, ( -- ( ISTEXT(VLOOKUP( Names, RelevantNamesList, 1, FALSE))) ), Amounts)
```

The actual result I get using the above code is a 0, which is obviously not correct.  I have also tried to use sumproduct, with no success.  I am beginning to think that I wont be able to use this without helper columns.

Is there a way to do this without helper columns?

Thanks in advance!
Jacqueline

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(<Names To Lookup>,<All Names List>)>0)*(COUNTIF(<Tasks To Lookup>,<All Tasks List>)>0)*<All Amounts List>)
```

So if you had a data setup like this:

[image]

Then the formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF($E$2:$E$3,$A$2:$A$5)>0)*(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$4,$B$2:$B$5)>0)*$C$2:$C$5)
```

**EDIT**:

Per comment, the lookup criteria could be partial matches.  For example, the name in the list is `Ms Jennifer Keim` and what's being looked up would be `Jennifer`.  In order to accomodate this, you'd need to switch tactics to the [DSUM function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dsum-function-53181285-0c4b-4f5a-aaa3-529a322be41b).  This means that you'll need to alter how you setup the criteria.

There are two ways to do this, the first is to create a row for each set of criteria you want, and the second is to have the limited list like you originally have and then setup criteria formulas you then feed into the DSUM.  Here's the data setup for the first scenario (note that the lookup headers must *exactly* match the table headers and that you're putting the wildcards for partial match directly in the criteria):

[image]

The DSUM formula in this scenario is:

```
=DSUM($A$1:$C$5,"Amount",$E$1:$F$7)
```

For the second scenario, we setup the limited criteria like you originally had it, but now we need helper formulas to feed into the DSUM.  Note that the helper formula headers must *not* be in your original datatable (here i've added "Check" to the end of the header names as an example):

[image]

The formulas need to reference the first cell in your datatable and perform the check against your criteria.  The DSUM formula will expand that formula's check against every row, so we only need this for the first row to establish the logic that DSUM will use.  Here are the two formulas for NameCheck (cell H2 in this example) and TaskCheck (I2).  We are using these formulas to allow for partial matches when looking up the criteria against the datatable:

- NameCheck: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,$E$2:$E$3,""))<LEN(A2)))`
- TaskCheck: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$F$2:$F$4,""))<LEN(B2)))`

Now the DSUM criteria argument references those formula cells and becomes:

```
=DSUM($A$1:$C$5,"Amount",$H$1:$I$2)
```

For further reading and information regarding the DSUM formula, Contextures has a great explanatory article with an example workbook you can download and experiment with: https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/11/15/dsum-and-excel-tables-sum-with-multiple-criteria/

Comment: tigeravatar, brilliant!  Thank you so much!  I struggled with this one for days, and your solution is quite eloquent!  I'm now wrestling with trying to have the countif do a substring-find, as would be needed if the column A values would be "Ms Jennifer Keim" or similar, so searching for the Jennifer substring.  I've researched that I may have to use something similar to "COUNTIF(rng,"*"&value&"*")>0" inside of the sumproduct, but I can't get the substitutions to work out.  Could I trouble you for a bit more advise on this one?

Comment: @Jacqueline Realized I had done DSUM incorrectly originally, please see newly updated answer for a corrected version with more explanation.